# How to swap data between row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

It seems familiar but this is new algorithm I want to swap the value between the old and new data. I want to get the latest data then set the data into NULL. I get the data raw from the PDF then convert it into Excel 'xls'.

```
DECLARE @MyTable1 TABLE (Id int, 
                         Code int, 
                         RoomNo int, 
                         Class nvarchar(10), 
                         Price nvarchar(100), 
                         Size nvarchar(100)
                        )

INSERT INTO @MyTable1(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) 
    SELECT 
        1, 3, 10, 'C', '15,275,400 16,275,425', '(17,009) (17,010)'

INSERT INTO @MyTable1(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) 
    SELECT 2, 3, 9, 'C', '14,893,500 15,893,575', '(16,580) (16,585)'

INSERT INTO @MyTable1(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) 
    SELECT 3, 3, 8, 'C', '14,446,700 15,446,743', '(16,080) (16,088)'

INSERT INTO @MyTable1(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) 
    SELECT 4, 3, 7, 'C', null, null

INSERT INTO @MyTable1(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) 
    SELECT 5, null, null, null, '13,905,000', '(15,484)' -- this is the old data

INSERT INTO @MyTable1(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) 
    SELECT 6, null, null, null, '14.185.000', '(15,796)' -- I need the latest data

INSERT INTO @MyTable1(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) 
    SELECT 7, 3, 47, 'E', '20,833,600 21,833,600', '(18,630) (18,635)'

INSERT INTO @MyTable1(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) 
    SELECT 8, 3, 46, 'E', '20,807,600 21,807,600', '(18,610) (18,611)'

INSERT INTO @MyTable1(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) 
    SELECT 9, 3, 45, 'E', '20,781,600 21,781,600', '(18,580) (18,588)'


SELECT * 
FROM @MyTable1
```

Current result:

```
Id          Code    RoomNo  Class   Price                       Size    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           3       10      C       15,275,400 16,275,425       (17,009) (17,010)
2           3       9       C       14,893,500 15,893,575       (16,580) (16,585)
3           3       8       C       14,446,700 15,446,743       (16,080) (16,088)
4           3       7       C       NULL                        NULL
5           NULL    NULL    NULL    13,905,000                  (15,484)
6           NULL    NULL    NULL    14.185.000                  (15,796)
7           3       47      E       20,833,600 21,833,600       (18,630) (18,635)
8           3       46      E       20,807,600 21,807,600       (18,610) (18,611)
9           3       45      E       20,781,600 21,781,600       (18,580) (18,588)
```

I want to achieve:

```
Id          Code    RoomNo  Class   Price                       Size    
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           3       10      C       15,275,400 16,275,425       (17,009) (17,010)
2           3       9       C       14,893,500 15,893,575       (16,580) (16,585)
3           3       8       C       14,446,700 15,446,743       (16,080) (16,088)
4           3       7       C       14.185.000                  (15,796)    -- get data from row 6 
5           NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL                        NULL
6           NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL                        NULL
7           3       47      E       20,833,600 21,833,600       (18,630) (18,635)
8           3       46      E       20,807,600 21,807,600       (18,610) (18,611)
9           3       45      E       20,781,600 21,781,600       (18,580) (18,588)

DECLARE @MyTable2 TABLE(Id int, Code int, RoomNo int, Class varchar(10), Price varchar(100), Size varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @MyTable2(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) SELECT 1, 3, 7, 'G', '7,147,000', '148,346 (13,771)'
INSERT INTO @MyTable2(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) SELECT 2, 3, 6, 'G', '7,111,000', '147,598 (13,701)'
INSERT INTO @MyTable2(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) SELECT 3, 3, 5, 'G', null, '146,872'
INSERT INTO @MyTable2(Id, Code, RoomNo, Class, Price, Size) SELECT 4, null, null, null, '7,637,000', '158,516 (14,715)'


SELECT * FROM @MyTable2
```

Current result:

```
Id  Code    RoomNo  Class       Price           Size
1   3       7       G           7,147,000       148,346 (13,771)
2   3       6       G           7,111,000       147,598 (13,701)
3   3       5       G           NULL            146,872
4   NULL    NULL    NULL        7,637,000       158,516 (14,715)
```

I need to achieve:

```
Id  Code    RoomNo  Class       Price           Size
1   3       7       G           7,147,000       148,346 (13,771)
2   3       6       G           7,111,000       147,598 (13,701)
3   3       5       G           7,637,000       158,516 (14,715)
4   NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL            NULL
```

Comment: SQL is a _relational_ database technology.  You need to give us the logical rules for the replacement, and then maybe we can give you a query.

Comment: Does "latest data" mean most dead since there are no dates? Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen there is information provided regarding the meaning of Columns and information regarding what is considered "latest row"

Comment: thanks for the advised friend, I'm sorry. Here, if Code, RoomNo, Class is not null and Price or Size or both is null then it's bad data. Then get the latest data and set the old to null.

Comment: You need to define 'latest data' based on the data (not based on what you can see visually)

Answer (score 0):

Let's roll the dice, **it seems we can put the definition of "*latest*" on the ID column, where bigger is latest**. Please note that, unlike printed data in our hands, databases aren't required to process data with some certain default order, so unless there's good reason (*usually us explicitly stating an order*), it will pick an order as its mood craves. That's what the people in comments were trying to convey, although they could have said it differently, especially you're probably a newcomer to DB stuff.

Next, data validity & correction, **you want to identify bad records, cross-check them with adjacent records**, and if it seems like a case of a record that got split in half, you want to merge it back to its original good state.

Based on your code, data samples, and the understanding I developed above, I think this code is what you're looking for. It's compatible with your code, and I commented around to explain what's what. **Please however, double-check the good/bad logic under the `IF EXISTS` boolean area, and the assumption of ID sequentiality in the `JOIN`s**.

```
DECLARE @CurId int = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM @MyTable1)
DECLARE @MinId int = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM @MyTable1)

WHILE @CurId > @MinId -- For all except the first.
BEGIN
    -- Start boolean.
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @MyTable1 AS Cur
        INNER JOIN @MyTable1 AS Prev ON Prev.Id = Cur.Id - 1 -- I'm assuming there are no gaps in IDs.
        WHERE Cur.Id = @CurId -- To limit checking to current ID.
          -- And for BIG, all left side is bad, all right side is good.
          AND (Cur.Code IS NULL AND Cur.RoomNo IS NULL AND Cur.Class IS NULL)
          AND (Cur.Price IS NOT NULL OR Cur.Size IS NOT NULL)
          -- And for SMALL, either same as BIG, or all left side is good, all right side is bad.
          AND 
          ( (   (Cur.Code IS NULL AND Cur.RoomNo IS NULL AND Cur.Class IS NULL)
                AND
                (Cur.Price IS NOT NULL OR Cur.Size IS NOT NULL)
            )
            OR
            (   (Prev.Code IS NOT NULL AND Prev.RoomNo IS NOT NULL AND Prev.Class IS NOT NULL)
                AND
                (Prev.Price IS NULL OR Prev.Size IS NULL)
    )     ) )
    -- End boolean.
    BEGIN
        -- Copy right side of this ID above once.
        UPDATE Prev
        SET Prev.Price = Cur.Price, Prev.Size = Cur.Size
        FROM @MyTable1 AS Prev
        INNER JOIN @MyTable1 AS Cur ON Cur.Id = Prev.Id + 1 -- I'm assuming there are no gaps in IDs.
        WHERE Cur.Id = @CurId
        -- NULL right side of this ID.
        UPDATE @MyTable1
        SET Price = NULL, Size = NULL
        WHERE Id = @CurId
    END

    SET @CurId -= 1 -- Gotta break them infinite loops.
END

SELECT * -- You shall not run this without my physical presence.
FROM @MyTable1
```